# Avoid this screen from appearing

Tags: boot, nvidia, login

I have Ubuntu 18 installed on my workstation and for some reason the below screen started appearing everytime before logging in and shutting down/restarting which is annoying to me. Any advice on how I can disable it from appearing?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the output from your grub configuration? You may read it with `nano /etc/default/grub` or `gedit /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Ubuntu 18??  As in Ubuntu Core 18?   The nvidia tag though seems to imply desktop, and desktop releases are all *year.month* in format, different products from the *snap* only releases which Ubuntu has had since 2016 which are signified by the use of *year* only in release.  Please clarify your release.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the normal system boot messages. These can be disabled in the configuration file `/etc/default/grub` with the option `quiet` on the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Check this line in your `/etc/default/grub`. Add `quiet` as an option if it is not there. After editing that configuration file, run `sudo update-grub` to transfer these settings to the grub boot system (that one does not directly used the configuration file).

Comment: I checked it and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` anything to change?

Comment: Do you have `plymouth` installed on your system? That's what provides the graphical "splash" screen when booting...

Comment: I am not sure, I installed Ubuntu 18.04 normally

Comment: What will happen if I removed `splash`?

Comment: These options work provided the system boots normally. Something else may be going on caused by that "for some reason" you indicate in your question. Add these options to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` and it will work in any case. However, that will not solve the issue why apparently the boot is not anymore proceeding in 'normal' mode.